# Opening a carbon c++ program from a custom url on OSx

Tags: c++, macos, url, command-line-arguments, macos-carbon

I have been able to set the plist for my project to open the project with a given url. However, I can't get it to pass params to the application (custom urls are built based on the user)

Is there a way to pass the params as command line arguments?

the scheme is essentially
url:userid

I need to be able to get the user id in the application. 
Is there a way to do this? I know with cocoa you can create an app delegate to handle this but I need a carbon way to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Install an Apple Event handler to recognize URLs (both the suite and the event name have the same four-character code, 'GURL').

The event's direct object is a URL string.  I would expect that string to contain the entire original URL, including any parameters that were encoded into it (e.g. if your custom scheme was `xyz://some/data?param1=abc&param2=def`, you should receive all of that).

Another important step is to register as a handler for that URL type in your `Info.plist` file.  Read up on `CFBundleURLTypes` for more.